# Specific Orderby with wordpress query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sql-order-by

I come to ask for your help, on a request with wordpress,
I have 2 columns, the first is always filled and the 2nd is sometimes empty. I would like to sort alphabetically according to the 2 columns, for example :

```
Col1    Col2      Will become
A     | D         D     | A
B     | C         F     | B
C     |           B     | C
D     | A         C     |
E     |           A     | D
F     | B         E     |
```

```
$custom_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'test',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        'clause1' => array(
                            'key' => 'key1',
                        ),
                        'clause2' => array(
                            'key' => 'key2',
                            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'orderby' => array(
                        'clause1' => 'ASC',
                        'clause2' => 'ASC',
                    ),
                    'paged' => $paged
                );
```

for the moment he sorts me column 1 and then column 2

```
Col1    Col2
C     |
E     |
D     | A
F     | B
B     | C
A     | D
```

A big thank you for your help

Comment: I think it is sorted by column 2 already, putting the empty ones at the top, followed by the rest in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

As i see in your example with "will become", column 1 is not used to be sorted by (nor DESC or ASC way).

So you just want to sort by column2 in ASC way. By the way, it's what you have in your result you tried : it's sorted by column2 ASC and not column1 (ASC or DESC) (empty is before any letter)

Am i wrong ? if i am, please update your example.